# How to convert datetime index into some decimal number?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have this data frame where data is sorted based on time starting at around 9:15:00. Using `df['t_factor'] = df.index.strftime("%H:%M:%S")` i converted index into only time values in an extra column. Now in this column, I want to represent this time with some decimal number, like say for 9:15:00 I want this to be converted into 9.25. Any idea how to do it in a single line?

The conversion formula is something like "9+15/60+0/3600", but I don't know how to access H, M, and S separately and write in a single line for the whole column.

Reference image [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using the original index rather than the new column, especially since the new column will be text.

```py
df["time_num"] = (
    df["Time"].dt.hour + df["Time"].dt.minute / 60 + df["Time"].dt.second / 3600
)
```

P.S. Are you sure you need to include seconds?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I get that I don't need second data, just kept for reference to make understand conversion formula.